# Using a heatmap to reflect differences between correlation dataframes and displaying only lower triangle

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, r-corrplot

[image: Correlation heat map]

I have the above heatmap that I generate using the below:

```
heat_map <- ggplot(melt_p4, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "white") +
  labs(title = "ST - LT Correlation Across Factor") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1)), size = 2.2)
```

where melt_p4 is

```
melt_p4 <- melt(p4)
```

and p4 is

```
p4 <- correlations_3months - correlations_history
```

where

```
correlations_3months <- round(cor(Raw_Index_3months_xts_Returns[-1,]),2)
correlations_history <- round(cor(Raw_Index_History_xts_Returns[-1,]),2)
```

The heatmap is basically a dataframe that subtracts a long term correlation dataframe from a short term correlation dataframe.  As such, I'm wondering if there's an argument I can use with the heatmap so that only the lower triangle (below the diagonal of all 0's) is displayed.  Otherwise I get a mirror image on the top and bottom half of the heat map.  Is that possible?

Also hoping I've provided enough code for this question.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `p4` is a matrix, you can use `upper.tri` as:

```
p4[upper.tri(p4)] <- NA
melt_p4 <- melt(p4)
melt_p4 <- melt_p4[!is.na(melt_p4$value),]

colnames(melt_p4) <- c("Var1", "Var2", "value")

ggplot(melt_p4, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "white") +
  labs(title = "ST - LT Correlation Across Factor") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1)), size = 2.2) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

#### Sample data

```
set.seed(1)
p4 <- matrix(runif(16, 0, 1), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)

row.names(p4) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
colnames(p4) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

Comment: This is great, thank you.  I've put that in the code in and that portion works fine (where melt_p4 melts only the non NA portion of the p4 matrix, but using the above ggplot no longer seems to work.  I know that I'm referencing two variables Var1/Var2, so how can I adjust the heat_map code so that the heat map is still produced?

Comment: that's perfect, thank you!  I may be asking for a bit much with this, but is it possible to reorder the image so that basically the column to the very left has every cell/tile filed?

Comment: You can add `melt_p4$Var1 <- factor(melt_p4$Var1, levels = levels(melt_p4$Var1)[ncol(p4):1])` before calling ggplot.